# How can I sell my biscuits?

Tags: farmville-country-escape

When I go to the market board there is nowhere to sell country biscuits. When I go to the help page there is no where to get a resolution. They list email help and live chat but there is no time to click on to get to those, and the question and answer forum only have the fact that you sell your biscuits and they don't count towards the quest. Well I would love to not be able to have it count toward my quest I just want to be able to sell them.

How do I sell them?

Answer (score 3):

i had this problem but to sell them you have to scroll a little bit left of your farm where the other things are and click on the market stall and sell the biscuits there, it does take a while for someone to buy them, but you wont be able to sell them on the farm board, only the market :) hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, in this case, it looks like you have to wait until there are biscuits on the board. Sell other things to clear up spaces, and hopefully biscuits will pop up. You can also take things off your board and wait for them to be replaced with new things, which can also help you get a chance to sell your biscuits.

Answer (score 0):

If you scroll to the left of your farm & click on the fruit stand you can sell them there.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Ben How this doesn't provide an answer?

Comment: It is incomplete. You should provide more information in your answer in the case that they *cannot* sell them this easily. The other answers are suggesting there is a criteria that needs to be met before being able to sell the items.

Comment: @Michel Furthermore it doesn't add anything that hasn't been said already. That was the reason I flagged.

Comment: It's a valid answer, not a great or even complete one as @ben pointed out. But, it's not wrong and should be flagged as *`not an answer: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.`*